# Refactoring getDefaultProps to ES6... what's wrong with my code ?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I've got the following `React.createClass` and I would like to pass it to a `extends React.Component` :

```
  var Rect = React.createClass({
        getDefaultProps: function() {
            return {
                width: 0,
                height: 0,
                x: 0,
                y: 0
            }
        },

        render: function() {
            return (
              <rect className="bar"
                    height={this.props.height} 
                    y={this.props.y} 
                    width={this.props.width}
                    x={this.props.x}
              >
              </rect>
            );
        },
    });
```

I give a shot but It doesn't work :

```
class Rect extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
    }
    render() {
        return (
          <rect className="bar"
                height={this.props.height} 
                y={this.props.y} 
                width={this.props.width}
                x={this.props.x}
          >
          </rect>
        );
    }
  Rect.defaultProps = { 
            width: 0,
            height: 0,
            x: 0,
            y: 0 
    }
};
```

So what's wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `defaultProps` definition needs to be outside of your class definition in this case:

```
class Rect extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
    }
    render() {
        return (
          <rect className="bar"
                height={this.props.height} 
                y={this.props.y} 
                width={this.props.width}
                x={this.props.x}
          >
          </rect>
        );
    }
};
Rect.defaultProps = { 
        width: 0,
        height: 0,
        x: 0,
        y: 0 
}
```